# Bitcoin distribution

Tags: scalability, wealth-distribution

Economies of scale are powerful and Bitcoin growth has been substantial over the past few years. Unfortunately much of the world including those in the 3rd world (many unbanked) who may need it most have yet to embrace Bitcoin.

Could distribuition statistics cause hesitation among later adopters? Some early adopters mined or purchased 10,000+ (even 100,000 in a few cases) BTC when they cost pennies each. Will that be enough to discourage those in the third world who might only be able to afford a fraction of one Bitcoin now?

Even if distribution does bother some people, will the economy of scale Bitcoin already enjoys versus all other cryptocurrencies (with different distribution models) be too much to make any alternative viable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A lot of people who accumulated thousands of coins in the early days spent them on silly things or cashed out during the 2012 bubble.  Lazlo for example, spent 10,000 bitcoins on two pizzas. Nobody knew that bitcoin would rise to the prices we briefly saw in 2013 or that we have today. The same thing will happen again, people have a price and will very likely sell on the way up thereby distributing their 'cheap' early coins to others; it should all balance out in a decade or two.